# How do i route a particular controller action to a particular form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am new to RoR and I was making a simple math_app. The addition function works fine. Now I'm trying to do a simple subtraction.The subtract controller is invoked and the subtract form is displayed but when I click on subtract the add controller gets invoked and an addition is performed. Where have I gone wrong?

This is my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'subtract/form'

  post 'subtract/result'

  get 'add/form'

  post 'add/result'
end
```

`result.html.erb`:

```
<%= @first %> - <%= @second %> = <%= @result %>
<br/>
<%= link_to 'back', subtract_form_path %>
```

`form.html.erb`: (This is the subtraction form)

```
<%= form_tag subtract_result_path do %>
  <%= number_field_tag :first %>
 -
  <%= number_field_tag :second %>
  <%= submit_tag "subtract" %>
<% end %>
```

`subtract_controller.rb`:

```
class SubtractController < ApplicationController
  def form
  end

    def result
        @first = params[:first].to_i
        @second = params[:second].to_i
        @result = @first - @second
    end
end
```

Comment: To me it looks fine. Can you show us what actual Subtract form looks like? View source code of the HTML page and paste it somewhere.

Comment: <form action="/add/result" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="r+utvrljmon5eHQGGDc4weHJqmv8BKe80ujPDUkriUsfaOfFAJbYEW1mSmsiiut21xFNVZdZ0GTVzl/6CQ/MkQ==" />
  <input type="number" name="first" id="first" />
 -
  <input type="number" name="second" id="second" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="subtract" />
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: that is a part of the html source code.... form action shows add/result...how do i change that?

Comment: what is the URL of this form? I mean actual url, when you took HTML source?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/subtract/form

Comment: i have it on bit bucket

Comment: see my answer. if it doesnot help, I will look at your code

Comment: What does your `rake routes` look like?

Comment: Prefix Verb URI Pattern                Controller#Action

subtract_form GET  /subtract/form(.:format)   subtract#form

subtract_result POST /subtract/result(.:format) subtract#result

add_form GET  /add/form(.:format)        add#form
    
 add_result POST /add/result(.:format)      add#result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in `views/substract/form.html.erb`. It now reads:

```
<%= form_tag add_result_path do %>
  <%= number_field_tag :first %>
 -
  <%= number_field_tag :second %>
  <%= submit_tag "subtract" %>
<% end %>
```

But it should be:

```
<%= form_tag substract_result_path do %>
  <%= number_field_tag :first %>
 -
  <%= number_field_tag :second %>
  <%= submit_tag "subtract" %>
<% end %>
```

You should probably also fix route

```
post '/subtract/result' => 'subtract#result', as: 'substract_result'
```

Also in `views/substract/result.html.erb`:

```
<%= @first %> - <%= @second %> = <%= @result %>
<br/>
<%= link_to 'back', subtract_form_path %>
```

Comment: its still not working. When i click subtract it still goes to the add result page